# CLISP: undefined function SHOW

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Starting REPL clisp-2.49-r8:

```
clisp -K full
```

Trying to execute something from DBUS module test
http://clisp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/clisp/clisp/modules/dbus/test.tst

```
(listp (show (multiple-value-list (ext:module-info "dbus" t)) :pretty t))
```

Getting:

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function SHOW
```

Where I can find this SHOW function?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...

It was defined in tests/tests.lisp

```
(defun show (object &key ((:pretty *print-pretty*) *print-pretty*))
 "Print the object on its own line and return it. Used in many tests!"
  (fresh-line) (prin1 object) (terpri) object)
```